# How can I use input from user that exist inside of if statement in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

So what I trying to do is ask users to put their weight and score of exam 1 & 2 and if they input the score, use those variables to figure out current score.

However, since scores are declared by users through scanner inside of if statement, it does not let me use those variables from outside of if statement. 
How can I use variable 'examOneScore' and 'examTwoScore' when I want to calculate csEx1 and csEx2.

When I try to use those it says "The local variable examOneScore may not have been initialized."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CurrentScore
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.printf("Weight of Exam 1: ");
       double weightExamOne = keyboard.nextDouble();

       System.out.printf("Weight of Exam 2: ");
       double weightExamTwo = keyboard.nextDouble();

       System.out.printf("Do you know your score of first exam? ");   
       String examOne = keyboard.nextLine();

       if(examOne.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || examOne.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))  
       {
           System.out.printf("Your score? ");
           double examOneScore = keyboard.nextDouble();
       }

       System.out.printf("Do you know your score of secondexam? "); 
       String examTwo = keyboard.nextLine();

       if(answerTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answerTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))  
       {
           System.out.printf("Your score? ");
           double examTwoScore = keyboard.nextDouble();
       }

       double csEx1 = (weightExamOne * examOneScore);
       double csEx2 = (weightExamTwo * examTwoScore );
     }
}
```

Comment: So what problem you are facing?

Comment: What do you want `examOneScore` to be if the user doesn't know the score of their first exam? If the answer is "I don't care", then what about `csEx1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the variables that you want to use later outside of the if statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("Weight of Exam 1: ");
    double weightExamOne = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("Weight of Exam 2: ");
    double weightExamTwo = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("Do you know your score of first exam? ");
    String examOne = keyboard.nextLine();

    double examOneScore = 1;
    if(examOne.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || examOne.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.printf("Your score? ");
        examOneScore = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.printf("Do you know your score of second exam? ");
    String examTwo = keyboard.nextLine();

    double examTwoScore = 1;
    if(examTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || examTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.printf("Your score? ");
        examTwoScore = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    double csEx1 = (weightExamOne * examOneScore);
    double csEx2 = (weightExamTwo * examTwoScore );
}
```

I used the value 1 for defining them, you have to look for yourself want you want to use there